# Mariadb: assignment operator (:=) not working with local variables

Tags: mysql, variables, stored-procedures, mariadb, variable-assignment

The Mariadb Knowledge base explains that the assignment operator (:=) works with both user-defined variables and local variables.

But when I make some tests, for example :

```
delimiter //
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE tst_PS_now()
BEGIN 
declare varnow datetime(3);
set varnow = (select now());
select 'result: ' ,varnow;
END;
//
delimiter ;

mysql:root>  call tst_PS_now() ;
+----------+-------------------------+
| result:  | varnow                  |
+----------+-------------------------+
| result:  | 2020-10-26 16:13:44.000 |
+----------+-------------------------+
```

example 2:

```
delimiter //
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE tst_PS_now()
BEGIN 
declare varnow datetime(3);
select varnow:=now();
select 'result: ' ,varnow;
END;
//
delimiter ;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':=now();  at line 4

In the second example, the assignment should work with my local variable.

I really need this kind of assignment in my stored procedures.
How may I fix it ? Any idea?

Comment: Your first example does not show the operator.

Comment: Try adding a space around the operator. so `varnow := now();`

Comment: Works fine with SET rather than select...which is what you had in the first sp.

Comment: From what I can see you can SELECT..INTO a local(declared) variable or SET it but you cannot assign a value to it using a select := or select =

Comment: tried  ```varnow := now() ``` and not working......              It seems that := is not working, despite explainations in Mariadb Knowledge Base.